# How can I get the Hibernate Configuration object from Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am trying to obtain Spring-defined Hibernate Configuration and SessionFactory objects in my non-Spring code. The following is the definition in my applicationContext.xml file:

Code:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
    </props>
   </property>
   <property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="dataSource"/>
   </property>
    </bean>
```

If I now call getBean("sessionFactory"), I am returned a $Proxy0 object which appears to be a proxy for the Hibernate SessionFactory object. But that isn't what I want - I need the LocalSessionFactoryBean itself because I need access to the Configuration as well as the SessionFactory.

The reason I need the Configuration object is that our framework is able to use Hibernate's dynamic model to automatically insert mappings at runtime; this requires that we change the Configuration and rebuild the SessionFactory.  Really, all we're trying to do is obtain the Hibernate config that already exists in Spring so that those of our customers that already have that information in Spring don't need to duplicate it into a hibernate.cfg.xml file in order to use our Hibernate features.

Comment: And how do you rebuild the sessionFactory? And how do you ensure that all existing transactions have finished before calling destroy?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One obscure feature of the Spring container is [the `&` prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.htmll#beans-factory-extension-factorybean):

> When you need to ask a container for
>   an actual `FactoryBean` instance
>   itself, not the bean it produces, you
>   preface the bean id with the ampersand
>   symbol `&` (without quotes) when
>   calling the `getBean` method of the
>   `ApplicationContext`. So for a given
>   `FactoryBean` with an id of `myBean`,
>   invoking `getBean("myBean")`  on the
>   container returns the product of the
>   `FactoryBean`, and invoking
>   `getBean("&myBean")` returns the
>   `FactoryBean` instance itself.

So in your case, using `getBean("&sessionFactory")` should return you the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` instance itself. Then you can call `.getConfiguration()` to get the `Configuration` object.

Comment: how can we @Autowire this ?

Comment: @skaffman Sairam Krish raised a good point. In case, how can I/we inject Hibernate values to, for instance, some field? I really want to have a field with the value of hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property. Do you know how can this be accomplished? Thanks in advance.