# override id name generated by jackson-datatype-hibernate

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-modules

Is it possible to override the name generated by **jackson-datatype-hibernate** Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS?

Currently it is serializing using full package name:

```
"client":{"com.test.domain.Client":1}
```

I want it to use id instead:

```
"client":{"id":1}
```

I am subclassing the ObjectMapper so maybe there is some method I can hook into

```
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        Hibernate4Module hbm = new Hibernate4Module();
        hbm.configure(Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
        registerModule(hbm);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem. I dig inside Jackson code and found out that if you create Hibernate4Module with Hibernate Mapping it should work.

So my solution looks as follows.

1. Standard Spring SessionFactory definition somewhere in my XML config:

   ```
   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        ...
   </bean>
   ```
2. I have custom Jackson object mapper defined also as a Spring bean:

   ```
   <bean class="my.own.HibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>
   ```
3. Now the key part. You need to inject LocalSessionFactoryBean into ObjectMapper:

   ```
   @Autowired
   public HibernateAwareObjectMapper(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean) {
       Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module = new Hibernate4Module(sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().buildMapping());
       hibernate4Module.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
       registerModule(hibernate4Module);
   }
   ```

I believe that as this code runs only once it should not have any significant performance impact. If you don't have ObjectMapper defined as a Spring bean you should be able to achieve the same via [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) and getBean() method with this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736147/380891.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I can't figure out how to get a handle on the localSessionFactoryBean in a spring boot app?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, following the advice here, I can get the SessionFactory, and then I can just cast that to Mappings  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33881946/228369

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I think it caused by `Hibernate`'s proxy.

I haven't a perfect solution recently, but you can solved it like this:

1. get the id, then create a new `com.test.domain.Client` object and set back to parent. then you will get `"client": {"id":1,...}`
2. Modify your entity, add one more id for just readable to the parent object, for example, `clientId`. Then you could avoid jackson to serialize the sub object. You will get `{..., "clientId":1,...}`

Hope some one can give more perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it in [my branch in github](https://github.com/mohsenkashi/jackson-datatype-hibernate) using `@Id` annotation.

you can use it (compile as jar file or use directly in code) or wait while [my pull request](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/pull/66) merged and new version release