# Spring Boot: Use Hibernate Session in a unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

In my Spring Boot application I access my Hibernate session as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881946/272180

Now I also want to access the Hibernate Session in a unit test.

How can I set up the datasource and access the Hibernate Session in a unit test of a Spring Boot application?

When I simply Autowire it, I get `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.`

Autowiring and using a `@Service` works flawlessly.

My unit-testing class looks like this atm:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = App.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class WebTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory  sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private UserService     userService;

    @Test
    public void testService() {

        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();

        // do something with users
        // ...

    }
}
```

`App.class` refers to the class with the main method which is used to run the Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the solution was as easy as adding `@Transactional` to the test-class.

After that I could use the `SessionFactory` as usual.