# Spring & Hibernate SessionFactory performance issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, sessionfactory

I am facing a performance issue with Hibernate sessionFactory. 
It is a Spring Boot - Hibernate app with a SessionFactory configured like this

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf){
    return hemf.getSessionFactory();
}
```

I have also tried all the different ways described in this question [Spring Boot - Handle to Hibernate SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063995/spring-boot-handle-to-hibernate-sessionfactory)

My DAO looks like this

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Transactional
public List<Type> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Type").list();
}
```

When the number of concurrent db requests is bigger than the configured maximumPoolSize(10 in this example) then the application becomes unresponsive.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stress-sessionfactory")
public void stressTest(@RequestParam int threadsCount) {
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
        final int k = i;
        Runnable runnable
                = () -> {

            List<Type> all = typeDAOHibernate.findAll();
            LOG.info("{}:sessionfactory:{} ", k, all.size());
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        threads.add(t);
    }
    threads.stream().forEach(t -> t.start());
}
```

You can find a standalone example in [github](https://github.com/ltsallas/spring-sessionfactory-stresstest). 
The example is configured with `maximumPoolSize=10`. 
So if you just hit 
 http://localhost:8080/stress-sessionfactory?threadsCount=11 you will get the error  I am talking about.

On the other hand a Spring Data repository can easily handle thousands of concurrent requests! (e.g http://localhost:8080/stress-jpa?threadsCount=2000)

I Have tried the same scenario with different datasources(Hikari, Tomcat) , different databases(oracle,h2) and different hibernate
versions( 5.011-Final,v4.3.11-Final) and I always get the same error.

Stacktrace

`Exception in thread "Thread-51" Exception in thread "Thread-47" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.example.dao.TypeDAOHibernate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6373e2e.findAll(<generated>)
    at com.example.controller.StressController.lambda$stressTest$0(StressController.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:591)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:194)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    ... 18 more
[]`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are injecting sessionFactory but not using spring-framework transaction features.
If you want to use like this you should close the session you are getting from sessionFactory in dao layer.

Comment: Hi, did you check your proposed solution? Did it worked? This doesn't look like it is the answer to the poster's question!

Comment: Yes findAll method is already marked as transactional. Other than that I tried to close the session manually in the method but the problem still occurs. This is not the case