# How to autowire Hibernate SessionFactory in Spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I've created a spring boot application, and I want to handle the Hibernate SessionFactory, so in my service class, I can just call the Hibernate SessionFactory as following :

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

I found a similar question in stackoverflow where I have to add the following line in application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
Cannot resolve property 'current_session_context_class' in java.lang.String
```

How can I solve this ?

## pom.xml dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` in your Spring configuration.

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

Have a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881946/676731

By Spring configuration I mean a class annotated with [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation or [`@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) (it is implicitly annotated with `@Configuration`).

Comment: by Spring configuration u mean the class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication`, right ?

Comment: That will throw a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean.

Also is marked as deprecated

Comment: it is deprecated

Answer (score 18):

Since version 2.0, JPA provides easy access to the APIs of the underlying implementations. The `EntityManager` and the `EntityManagerFactory` provide an `unwrap` method which returns the corresponding classes of the JPA implementation.

In the case of Hibernate, these are the `Session` and the `SessionFactory`.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

Comment: Your  solution will throw a:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null. 
entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) has to be called when needed it. Also I'm used to old Transaction manager and I had to change the classic sessionFactory.getCurrentTransaction(); to sessionFactory.openTransaction(); 
I'm really hoping it won't ignore the Spring managed transaction.

Comment: This API has changed. You now need to use `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class); SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory()`