# Unable to autowire sessionFactory in springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Please find below my `daoImpl` class.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    // all my setter  and other methods
}
```

`pom.xml` :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My springBoot app code:

```
package com.sagarp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class EmployeeHibernateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeHibernateApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8080
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true   

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sagarp?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password_123


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

Scenario: 
When I start my springboot app, it is **unable to autowire the `sessionFactory` object.**

**P.S: I am aware that I can use the ``spring-jpa`and`crud repository` instead of hibernate.
Thing is I have to use hibernate. Think of it as a restriction.**

Error:

**Description:
Field sessionFactory in com.sagarp.employee.EmployeeDaoImpl required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.**

Could anyone help me a bit here

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895643/how-to-autowire-hibernate-sessionfactory-in-spring-boot) It need property in application.properties and bean in your configuration file.

Comment: try autowire EntityManager and invoke unwrap to SessionFactory

Comment: you can take reference from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893879/spring-boot-thymeleaf-hibernate-sessionfactory-bean-with-java-annotations/45894600#45894600

Comment: There is no `SessionFactory` there is an `EntityManagerFactory`. The fact that you have to use Hibernate doesn't mean you cannot use JPA... Hibernate is an (the reference?) implementation for JPA, so start with plain JPA and if you really need the plain hibernate API use `entitymanager.unwrap(Session.class)` to get the underlying session.

Comment: @mallikarjun have tried that, but it is of no help.

Comment: Are you aware that Hibernate *is* JPA? (As of the latest versions, `SessionFactory extends EntityManagerFactory`.)

Comment: @chrylis that is only the case for Hibernate 5.2 and later, prior to that that wasn't the case.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thus "latest versions".

Comment: Although in the latest versions that is the case that also lead to issues on Spring 5.0 trying to combine Hibernate and JPA (transactionamangement for instance). Fixes are being made for Spring 5.1.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the help. I used `entityManagerFactory`

Answer (score -1):

**In case if you wanted to know the code for SessionFactory in Hibernate with version lesser than 5.2**

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 static {
     try {
         sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
     } catch (Throwable ex) {
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);

     }

 }
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
     return sessionFactory;
 }
```