# How Can I set sessionFactory properties using application.properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I want to connect H2 - Embeded using Spring Boot. I want to use SessionFactory. I know how to do with web.xml with applicationContext.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

But when I start with spring initializr, I want to use application.properties configuration to connect database with SessionFactory and Session, but it gets fail. It gives me :

required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password= 

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework 
    .orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-      
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
```

I have already downloaded needed hibernate.

I am simply searching sessionFactory configuration to connect database.

My pom.xml like this:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

My UserDaoImpl:

```
import com.alpcan.springproject.dao.UserDao;
import com.alpcan.springproject.model.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<User> allUsers(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
        List<User> users=query.list();
        return users;

    }
}
```

P.S : Can I use RpaRepository instead of SessionFactory? What will be difference? Will be any speed performance ? Which one is better?

If RpaRepository is strong, I just want to use it.

Comment: Did you add dependency|?

Comment: I just new added my pom.xml above. Did I miss any dependencies?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063995/spring-boot-handle-to-hibernate-sessionfactory

Comment: Example project how to do this: https://github.com/mdeinum/samples/tree/master/spring-boot-plain-hibernate

Comment: Just use the `EntityManager` instead of a `SessionFactory` with the current state of JPA there is little advantage in using plain hibernate. If you really want to use the session you can always do `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`. Also the `org.hibernate` and `jpa` dependencies are already included in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, no need to add them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new learner at Spring Boot. Do you have any link that can I learn from how to use EntityManager ? Because everything gets complicated in my mind. I dont want any errors, a week passed and cant write code because of errors :/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Is it really provided by you on runtime??

change scope to `compile`